# Add new "col" to an existing two-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensional array:

```
$arr= array();
array_push($arr, array('col1' => 'someval', 'col2' => 'someval'));
array_push($arr, array('col1' => 'someval', 'col2' => 'someval'));
```

Now I want to add a new "col" to each 2nd level array like `'col3' => 'someval'`. How to do that?

Comment: @u_mulder OK, but how to "append" it?

Comment: `foreach ($arr as &$item) { $item['col3'] = 'value'; }`

Comment: @u_mulder That's it. Cheers. Give it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: as u said to each level `array_push($arr, array('col1' => 'someval', 'col2' => 'someval','col3'=>'someval'));
array_push($arr, array('col1' => 'someval', 'col2' => 'someval','col3'=>'someval'));`

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh As I said adding to an existing one, afterwards...

Comment: :) may be its mine misconception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `[]` notation to add a value with key `key`:

```
foreach ($arr as &$item) { 
    $item['col3'] = 'value'; 
}
```

Use `&` with `$item` so as pass each array of `$arr` by reference.

Comment: One more Q if I may. Can I define the name of the col (`col3`) from a variable? I can't do it like this `$item[$variable_string] = 'value';`.